# ExpressionEngine transferring variable for title name

Tags: php, content-management-system, dynamic-data, expressionengine

For some reason I thought this should work but its eluding me

I have two templates a header and a generic index

Template: index

```
{html_head} <!-- Global Var -->
  {embed="Broadcom/html_header" page_title="Home"} <!-- var page_title=Home?? -->
{html_close} <!-- Global Var -->
```

And then I have my header

```
<?php require('php/libraries/BukBuilder.class.php'); ?>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-2" />

    <?php BukBuilder::init(); ?>
    <?php BukBuilder::style('style.css'); ?>
    <?php BukBuilder::script('modernizr.js'); ?>

    <title>{embed:page_name} | {site_label}</title>
</head>
```

For some reason though my variable page_title is not producing `Home` or whitespace when called with `{embed:page_name}` though, did I miss something? mess something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My grammar was wrong, I was using `_title` on one part and `_name` on the other.
Sorry guys, sometimes its the stupidest things